postfix with Maildir config still delivers to Mailbox
I want to have virtual accounts with Maildir, so I figured out the following main.cf
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_mailbox_domains = mydomain.com
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000

but the email gets delivered in Mailbox format not Maildir. What am I doing wrong?
/etc/postfix/vmaps is:
test@mydomain.com mydomain.com/test


That's because first you have to change your dovecot config:
vim /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf
Look for "mail_location" config variable, and then "location" var in your active namespace. Check the below example:
config snippet

EDIT: If you still insist on staying with postfix - change:
/etc/postfix/vmaps is: test@mydomain.com mydomain.com/test
by adding a slash after username, so it looks like this:
/etc/postfix/vmaps is: test@mydomain.com mydomain.com/test/

Source - official postfix documentation, specifically:

If the lookup result ends in a slash ("/"), maildir-style delivery is carried out, otherwise the path is assumed to specify a UNIX-style mailbox file.


It appears I completely misunderstood how postfix works. I thought postfix will deliver to Maildir on it's own. What if I do not want to use IMAP at all ?

I strongly advise not to use postfix for mailbox management. If you don't want IMAP (WHY?!?) you can use POP3 and handle SMTP authentication via dovecot.
If you still insist on staying with postfix - change:
/etc/postfix/vmaps is: test@mydomain.com mydomain.com/test
by adding a slash after username:
'/etc/postfix/vmaps is: test@mydomain.com mydomain.com/test/'

@ratatata Postfix can deliver to Maildir on its own, but it can also be configured to deliver through an LDA such as procmail, or it can be configured to deliver through Dovecot (either via dovecot-lda or via LMTP). I think mrd83 assumes that you have it set up with either dovecot-lmtp or dovecot-lda, and it's probably a good idea to check your postconf -n to find out for sure.

@u1686_grawity
I assumed exactly that. Updated my answer with postfix-only solution though.

The answer was super simple but I could not figure it out, thank you
